# Python unable to import socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to make a IRC twitch bot, however I am runnning into an issue when importing socket

Whenever I run the program I get an error:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\VERYLONGPATH\ChatBot\run.py", line 6, in <module>
    s = openSocket()
  File "C:\VERYLONGPATH\ChatBot\socket.py", line 5, in openSocket
    s = socket.socket()
```

And here is the actual python code:

run.py

```
from socket import openSocket
from initialize import joinRoom

s = openSocket()
joinRoom(s)

while True:
    presist = True
```

socket.py

```
import socket
from settings import HOST, PORT, PASS, ID, CHANNEL

def openSocket():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.send("PASS " + PASS + "\r\n")
    s.send("NICK " + ID + "\r\n")
    s.send("JOIN #" + CHANNEL + "\r\n")
    return s
```

I am unsure what could be causing this error, as I am importing socket.

Comment: One thing I would like to point out is that you didn't put what type of connection it would be SOCK_STREAM, AF_INET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.py` has the same name as another module, `socket`, so Python is getting confused as to which `socket` you mean when you do `from socket import openSocket`; it decides to import the module rather than your file. Python then throws this error because the `socket` module doesn't have an `openSocket` function.

To fix this, change the name of your `socket.py` file to something else, for example `mysocket.py`, and then change your code in `run.py` accordingly like this:

```
from mysocket import openSocket
...
```